# Restrict Chatter Access for Login As functionality

Tags: chatter, grant-login-access

If a delegated Admin logs in as other user, he can view, create & delete feed/posts for the user.

He can even read posts from private groups.

Is it possible that we can put some restriction in this scenario? Not allowing any one other than user to access his chatter posts.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible because when you log in as someone you inherit all the permissions, and there is no way to customize this functionality.